# Interrupted download not resuming in curl

Tags: curl

Downloading a file using command `curl -O https://asdf.com/xyz.rar`. Now suppose the download is interrupted, so resuming download using `curl -O -C -https://asdf.com/xyz.rar`,the following error appears `curl: option -C: expected a positive numerical parameter`.How to solve this problem ?

Platform: Windows 7 Professional 2009
Curl version : curl 7.77.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.77.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1k (Schannel) zlib/1.2.
brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.0 libidn2/2.3.1 libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.43.0 libgsasl/1
0.0
Release-Date: 2021-05-26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it may help

```
curl -C - -O https://asdf.com/xyz.rar
```

Comment: Happy to help,  Please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: If I want to follow redirects to download a file, should I use `curl -L -C - -O https://asdf.com/xyz`  ?

Comment: Sure, you can try, -L helps in redirect downloads.